# Fastlane testing tries to boot another device

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, fastlane

I'm starting project unit tests via fastlane.

I have 2 devices for testing: *iPad Air 2* and *iPhone 6 plus*.

But in console I can see next lines:

```
SimDevice: iPhone 6 Plus (<device code removed>, iOS 11.4, Booted)
(11.4 (15F79))
2018-11-16 14:34:45.608 xcodebuild[42659:1368186]
iPhoneConnect: ## Unable to mount developer disk image, 
(Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=601 "Could not 
locate device support files." UserInfo={DeviceType=iPhone9,3, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Could not locate device support files., 
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) 
is running iOS 12.0 (16A366), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.})
```

The question is for which tasks does it try to mount disk image and boot iPhone 7 for tests? Btw it loops on this.

What does it mean?

Note: I have 2 XCode's - 9 and 10. Maybe it affects somehow.

**Edit 1**.

I do start tests via `scan` (it is alias) command:

```
scan(
        workspace: "Name.xcworkspace",
        scheme: "Name",
        clean: false,
        devices: devices_for_testing
    )
```

Btw, tests finally completed, but I want to know, why has this output appeared.

Comment: How are you starting unit tests with fastlane? What is your `Fastfile`, the lane executed? What other output do you have before that looping problem?

Comment: @janpio I have updated an answer